# get current URL path and assign 'active' and add class from foreach laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[i want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPCbF.png) why class alert alert-success cannot add to tag a href?

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="nav">
   @foreach($menu as $d)
   <li role="presentation"><a class="text-capitalize " href="{!! $d->name !!}">{!! $d->name !!}</a></li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
   // get current URL path and assign 'active' class
   var pathname = window.location.pathname;
   $('.nav > li > a[href="'+pathname+'"]').parent().addClass('alert alert-success');
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following

```
$('.nav > li > a[href*="'+pathname+'"]').parent().addClass('alert alert-success');
```

Comment: you want a picture for what?

Comment: better if you do this with php